# Call ajax call after facebook user send invite request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know where should I put my ajax call when the user clicks the send request button on the fb ui invite. Currently, I put it after the fb ui syntax:

```
function sendRequest(gFriendID, gFriendName) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        title: 'Check out LoyaltyNmore!',
        to: gFriendID,
        message: 'Hi ' + gFriendName + ' join me in earning loyalty points!',
    }, fbCallback);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/home/StoreInvite?userId=" + gFriendID,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (err) {

        }
    })
}
}
```

But as expected. The ajax call gets executed when the app opens up the request UI. I want the ajax call to be executed right after the user clicks send request not when the request UI shows. Also when cancel is clicked. I don't want my ajax call to be executed. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to put your ajax call inside the facebook callback function... The response will contain details about to whom the app was shared. The 'to' array will get you the ids of those who were invited.

```
function sendRequest(gFriendID, gFriendName) {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'Check out LoyaltyNmore!',
    to: gFriendID,
    message: 'Hi ' + gFriendName + ' join me in earning loyalty points!',
  }, function(response)
  {
    if(response.to.length)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/home/StoreInvite?userId=" + gFriendID,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (err) {

        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was really wondering what the callback is all about. But when I checked the browser console. I saw some details being displayed and played with it.

Comment: Callbacks are always for this purpose. Callback refers to something that is called/executed after whatever it is associated with is done. Let it be for FB api or JQuery,etc.